# apche2 proxypass contexte path

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, apache2, proxypass

Please i have apche configuration like this:

```
       <Location /admin/>
              Deny from all                      
              Allow from 127.0.0.1
           ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8027/
           ProxyPassReverse /
        </Location>
```

everything work fine but in logout i have a redirect to cas server:https://casServer/cas/.... but this url has bee modified  to https://localhost/admin/cas/.... and i think it has bee modified by ProxyPassReverse.

please can any one help me thank you

Comment: Did you test your hypothesis (by removing the `ProxyPassReverse` directive)?

Comment: yes in this case the application didn't work i got this url https://localhost/app/ without admin